# Elasticsearch: compare a record with previous record

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to query companies' financial data in our elastic search database. I indexed data from the SQL database to es with the parent-child relationship.
Parent data contains common information of companies, like this:

| OrganId | OrganCode | OrganName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Code1 | Name 1 |
| 2 | Code2 | Name 2 |

Child data contains financial data. There are more than 1000 indicators of financial data, divided into groups such as `BalanceSheets`, `IncomeStatements`, etc... In this question, I just take `Revenue` indicator for example:

| OrganId | YearReport | Revenue | DataType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018 | 500.000 | IncomeStatement |
| 1 | 2019 | 550.000 | IncomeStatement |
| 1 | 2020 | 450.000 | IncomeStatement |
| 1 | 2021 | 600.000 | IncomeStatement |
| 2 | 2018 | 500.000 | IncomeStatement |
| 2 | 2019 | 550.000 | IncomeStatement |
| 2 | 2020 | 450.000 | IncomeStatement |
| 2 | 2021 | 600.000 | IncomeStatement |

There are more than 1000000 companies in our database.
Below is a design of the company search function
[image]

There are many search criteria. I'm stuck with a search query, where the data in this record has to be compared with the previous record. The search clauses can be verbalized as follows:

- Find companies whose revenue is greater than (or less than) last year's revenue
- Find companies whose revenue is greater than (or less than) the largest revenue of the last three years
- Find companies whose revenue is greater than (or less than) the last three years' average
- ...

My work has been behind schedule for more than 2 weeks now because I can't find a solution. I've searched a lot on the forums, but still haven't found an answer. Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: can you please add how you have index parent-child data in elasticsearch ? did you use two seperate index or join data type in es

Comment: @SagarPatel I used data type, followed by this article: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/master/parent-child-relationships.html

Comment: got it, you have used join data type. Allt he question you have meniotned are mostly achivable using aggregation in Elasticsearch.

Comment: @SagarPatel can you give more detail about the keyword I need to research?

Comment: Please check [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/search-aggregations-metrics-avg-aggregation.html). i will try it out and post answer.

Comment: @SagarPatel any update? please

Comment: @SagarPatel I am waiting for your answer

Comment: I didn’t get enough time to check on this. Did you try out aggregation as I mentioned in comment.